# Hamiltonian w.r.t. to Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

How can I express an arbitrary Hamiltonian w.r.t. to his Lagrangian.

Attempt:

$
H = \sum{\dot{q} p} - L
$

with

$
p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}
$

and

$
\dot{p} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}
$

So

$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} =-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}
$

We can derivate:

$
\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(
\sum_k{\dot{q_k}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_k}}} - L\right) =-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}
$

$
\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(
\dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} - L\right) 
$

$
\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} + \dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}=-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}
$

So simply:

$
\dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}+\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}= 0
$

It can be written as Euler Lagrange équation offseted.

$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} + \dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}} = 0
$

Is that mean $\dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial q \partial \dot{q}}$ is necessary 0?

Is that formulation correct? Am I mistaken Somewhere?

Comment: Question *is* worth answering.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thanks for your relevant feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem arises because you are quite carelessly switching between two different sets of variables. The derivative $\partial_q \mathcal L(q, \dot q)$ is not the same as $\partial_q \mathcal L(q, p_q)$.
In particular, in terms of variables $(q,p_q)$, $\partial_q \dot q(q,p_q)$ is not necessarily $0$.

You should repeat this calculation with attention to the coordinates in which you are performing each differentiation. A convenient notation trick borrowed from thermodynamics is to write all the independent variables in a subscript for each differentiation $\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial q}\right)_{\dot q}$ is the derivative performed in coordinates $(q,\dot q)$ i.e. the derivative of the function $\mathcal L(q, \dot q)$, while $\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial q}\right)_{p_q}$ is performed in the coordinates $(q, p_q)$, i.e. the derivative of the function $\mathcal{L}(q,p_q)$. To be clear, in the coordinates $(q, p_q)$, $\dot q$ is not independent - it becomes a function $\dot q(q,p_q)$ and the Lagrangian can be expressed via the composition $\mathcal{L}(q,p_q) = \mathcal L(q,\dot q(q, p_q))$.

Comment: Yes, this is it. When one writes the Hamiltonian thus, $H=\sum p\dot q-L$, one is in fact doing a Legendre transformation like the ones in thermodynamics.